# GNU Parallel running a code having several options

Tags: parallel-processing

I have to admit that I was reading the gnu parallel documentation and I couldn't
find what I was looking for.
I need to run a code that has several options. The code is math intensive and it takes up to 5 days  in a 3Ghz computer running in a single core.
I've used gfortran  with -fopemp before but now I'm running this C code so gnu parallel seems adequate. Now to the issue, I need to execute wcmap.c with the following options using nice and nohup:

```
nohup nice -n 19 ./wcmap --slon_min 74.5 --slon_max 74.5 --ll_0_min 325 --ll_0_max 340 --bet_min 0.0 --bet_max 15 --vg 38.9 --ll_0_step 0.5 --bet_step 0.5 --path PARALLEL/ MORHIST-Exit.dat
```

I've tried gnu parallel with no success

```
parallel --gnu nice -n 19 ./wcmap --slon_min 74.5 --slon_max 74.5 --ll_0_min 325 --ll_0_max 340 --bet_min 0.0 --bet_max 15 --vg 38.9 --ll_0_step 0.5 --bet_step 0.5 --path PARALLEL/ MORHIST-Exit.dat  :::
```

I need to leave this running on several nodes for some days in a remote server. Or even at my office computer (4 cores), that's why I'm using nohup from a remote session.
Any suggestions are appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
Sebastian

Comment: It seems that quoting the commands actually works, but I still get the "parallel: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit." message. It's running on two threads now.

Comment: Did you start by reading and understanding the examples? http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__working_as_xargs__n1__argument_appending

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel cannot magically parallelize the internals of your wcmap program. What it can do is to run wcmap with different parameters in parallel. So let us assume you want to run:

```
./wcmap --slon_min 74.5 --slon_max 74.5 MORHIST-Exit.dat
./wcmap --slon_min 75 --slon_max 75 MORHIST-Exit.dat
./wcmap --slon_min 75.5 --slon_max 75.5 MORHIST-Exit.dat
./wcmap --slon_min 76 --slon_max 76 MORHIST-Exit.dat
```

Then you can do that with GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ./wcmap --slon_min {} --slon_max {} MORHIST-Exit.dat ::: 74.5 75 75.5 76
```

Comment: Thank you Ole. Yes, several runs in solar longitude are required. I was aware of this, but I don't know it it would make a difference. Each core is actually one thread, and I was expecting several threads per core. So the 24 cores available to me are actually 24 threads. I will start manually those runs, one per thread, taking all the threads. Thank you again!